# Efficient way to copy postgres data to ADLS thru Python

Tags: python, postgresql, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am reading data from Postgres table and I need to write the same in ADLS.
My current approach is to read the table, store the result into local file and then write the local file into Azure data lake.

Please let me know if it is possible to write data directly to ADLS from postgres without the temporary local file.

For testing purpose, I have move the data in csv format. I am ok with parquet or orc format too if I am able to skip the intermediate local file.

My current working code :

```
import psycopg2
from azure.storage.filedatalake import FileSystemClient

conn_Str = "conn_Str"
file_system = FileSystemClient.from_connection_string(conn_Str, file_system_name="file_system_name")

try:

    connection = psycopg2.connect(database="db",user="usr",password="pwd",host="localhost")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "COPY (select * from schema.table) TO STDOUT WITH CSV DELIMITER ';'"
     with open(r"/dir1/dir2/table.csv", "w") as file:
        cursor.copy_expert(sql, file)
        print ("file written")
        
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    print("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)

finally:
    # closing database connection.
    if connection:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
#Writing the local file to ADLS
file_system = FileSystemClient.from_connection_string(conn_Str, file_system_name="container")
directory_client = file_system.get_directory_client("dir1/subdir")
file_client = directory_client.get_file_client("table-file.csv")
local_file = open(r"/dir1/dir2/table.csv",'r')
file_contents = local_file.read()
file_client.upload_data(file_contents, overwrite=True)
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain the bigger picture? Copying from SQL to CSV does not seem to be efficient. I'm afraid you're looking for a solution for a badly optimized situation

Comment: format does not matter for me. I m fine with parquet or orc format too. Will edit the question.

Comment: My question was: in which situation do you need to access files if you have the data in a database? A database seems much faster

Comment: I am creating a data lake and my requirement to pull data from various sources like postgres, api and write it into adls.

Comment: You're still not explaining why. If you already have the data in a database, it seems very counterintuitive to copy the data into a CSV file.

Comment: I need to perform ETL operations thru Azure. Trying to extract all the sources to ADLS and then apply transformation on the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233005/discussion-between-madhanlal-and-be-chiller-too).

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in the chat, I think you should use Azure Data Factory to copy data from a database to a flat file.

Comment: Thanks. We are exploring the options of doing things programatically.